# CakePHP Self-Refreshing Database Entry Script

Tags: mysql, cakephp-1.3, large-files

Ok, so basically I've got a script in CakePHP where I'm putting over 7 million records into a database. Seeing as how there are that many records, I'm running into some issues with timeouts. This is on a personal server so the memory limit is set to 2000MB so that's not really an issue with how I'm wanting to do it.

The database rows are coming from a huge file. The file was too big for the memory limit, I've split it up into 101 pieces at 10000 lines in each file.

I want the page to refresh after 10 records, and when it comes back, restart inserting records where it left off.

Any ideas?

I've tried the $this->redirect() route, but it's created never-ending scripts that had to be stopped by manually restarting the server.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not using a shell for that?

To avoid the redirect loop you could try to redirect between two actions or try to attach a timestamp to the url. I'm not sure if that will work, the shell would be the much better approach anyways.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by shell...This application is going to be used by other people and so it has to be very user friendly so it can be used by normal people with no knowledge of PHP or Linux.